# Comparing a list value with Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to randomly pick a state from the available state (key): capital(value) dictionary list and then try to match the state picked against the dictionary to return the capital city.

My code so far:

```
capitals = {
'Alabama' : 'Montgomery',
'Alaska' : 'Juneau',
'Arizona' : 'Phoenix',
'Arkansas' : 'Little Rock',
'California' : 'Sacramento',
'Colorado' : 'Denver',
'Connecticut' : 'Hartford',
'Delaware' : 'Dover',
'Florida' : 'Tallahassee',
'Georgia' : 'Atlanta',
'Hawaii' : 'Honolulu',
'Idaho' : 'Boise',
'Illinois' : 'Springfield'}

name_list=list(zip(capitals.keys()))
print(name_list)

from random import *
random_state=list(choice(name_list))
print(random_state)

for key,value in capitals.items():
    if random_state in  key:
        print(value)
```

I am getting an error

> TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list

**Expected output** is Denver if the random state picked was Colorado

Thanks

Comment: What is your question? The error message apparently is pretty clear that you can describe the problem yourself, the left operand, `random_state` needs to be a `str` not a list. You **made it a list**. What are you missing here?

Comment: Also, why `name_list=list(zip(capitals.keys()))`??? You almost certainly just want `name_list = list(capitals)`, why are you using `zip`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `TypeError` because `random_state` is `tuple` of one element and you try to check if `tuple` contains in key which is `string`.

`['Florida'] in 'Alabama'`

Just remove `zip` from your code and you will get list of strings, however now you have list of tuples. And your code will check if `string` contains in `string`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> capitals = {
...     'Alabama': 'Montgomery',
...     'Alaska': 'Juneau',
...     'Arizona': 'Phoenix',
...     'Arkansas': 'Little Rock',
...     'California': 'Sacramento',
...     'Colorado': 'Denver',
...     'Connecticut': 'Hartford',
...     'Delaware': 'Dover',
...     'Florida': 'Tallahassee',
...     'Georgia': 'Atlanta',
...     'Hawaii': 'Honolulu',
...     'Idaho': 'Boise',
...     'Illinois': 'Springfield'
... }
>>> random_state = choice(list(capitals))
>>> capitals[random_state]
'Springfield'
```

Comment: `list(capitals.keys())` -> `list(capitals)`

Comment: This, however I'd use capitals.get(random_state) and you can remove .keys()

Comment: @AntonvBR I'm not sure that `.get` is necessary in this case since (currently) the random "states" are only being picked from the `capitals` dict (shouldn't be any keyerrors?)

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Yeah, you are probably right, I prefer it in situations like these but no biggy.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

First, you aren't generating name_list correctly. It should just be:

name_list=capitals.keys()

Second, generate random_state as a list. Get rid of the list() and it should work:

random_state=choice(name_list)

Comment: `choice(capitals.keys())` raises `TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing` in Python 3

Answer (score 0):

All of what you have seems to be replaceable by this since you're only pulling back one state with choice.

```
import random
print(capitals[random.choice(list(capitals))])
```

Since it's just one state, this just pulls back the value of that key directly instead of using a for loop to look through all of the keys.

Comment: This is useless as the variable is not stored. You could just random a value then.

Comment: The example is just printing something.  I am providing alternate code achieving what the OPs code appears to be trying to do.